# gpg private key not valid when used in github secrets

Tags: github, continuous-integration

I am currently trying to set up my CI in github enterprise where one step involves the usage of git secret. I'd like to use the following command in my CI

```
echo -e "$GPG_PRIVATE_KEY" | gpg --batch --yes --passphrase "$GPG_PASSPHRASE" --import
```

I created both secrets `GPG_PRIVATE_KEY` `GPG_PASSPHRASE` under the Secrets tab in github and the passphrase is also working just fine (tested with other commands). But I can't get the private key working. I used the output from `gpg --armor --export-secret-key myapp@test.com` but apparently thats not a valid format since the CI tells me

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Can github not handle the format from the export command or what am i doing wrong?